# How to click a button on Dojo-heavy web

Tags: python, selenium, dojo

I met a problem while doing auto web test by using python+selenium+phantomjs.
The web is Dojo-heavy web app. In order to modify record, I need to first click drop_button `修改`, and then click "modify"
but it always report cannot find element.

Can someone please help me looking into this? The "modify" element is `display:none`, I tried to use JS to enable it, but failed.

[image]

Here is the source of `修改` element

```
<div class="dijit dijitLeft dijitInline dijitDropDownButton" dojoattachevent="onmouseenter:_onMouse,onmouseleave:_onMouse,onmousedown:_onMouse,onclick:_onDropDownClick,onkeydown:_onDropDownKeydown,onblur:_onDropDownBlur,onkeypress:_onKey" widgetid="dijit_form_DropDownButton_6">
    <div class="dijitRight">
        <button class="dijitStretch dijitButtonNode dijitButtonContents" type="button" dojoattachpoint="focusNode,titleNode" wairole="button" waistate="haspopup-true,labelledby-dijit_form_DropDownButton_6_label" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-labelledby="dijit_form_DropDownButton_6_label" id="dijit_form_DropDownButton_6" tabindex="-1" aria-valuenow="" aria-disabled="false">
            <div class="dijitInline " dojoattachpoint="iconNode"></div><span class="dijitButtonText" dojoattachpoint="containerNode,popupStateNode" id="dijit_form_DropDownButton_6_label">修改</span><span class="dijitA11yDownArrow">▼</span>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the source of `modify` element :

```
<table class="dijit dijitMenu dijitReset dijitMenuTable" wairole="menu" dojoattachevent="onkeypress:_onKeyPress" role="menu" id="dijit_Menu_32" widgetid="dijit_Menu_32" style="display: none;">
    <tbody class="dijitReset" dojoattachpoint="containerNode">
        <tr class="dijitReset dijitMenuItem" dojoattachevent="onmouseenter:_onHover,onmouseleave:_onUnhover,ondijitclick:_onClick" id="dijit_MenuItem_76" widgetid="dijit_MenuItem_76" tabindex="-1">
            <td class="dijitReset">
                <div class="dijitMenuItemIcon " dojoattachpoint="iconNode"></div>
            </td>
            <td tabindex="-1" class="dijitReset dijitMenuItemLabel" dojoattachpoint="containerNode" wairole="menuitem" role="menuitem" aria-disabled="false">Modify</td>
            <td class="dijitReset" dojoattachpoint="arrowCell">
                <div class="dijitMenuExpand" dojoattachpoint="expand" style="display:none"><span class="dijitInline dijitArrowNode dijitMenuExpandInner">+</span></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="dijitReset dijitMenuItem" dojoattachevent="onmouseenter:_onHover,onmouseleave:_onUnhover,ondijitclick:_onClick" id="dijit_MenuItem_77" widgetid="dijit_MenuItem_77" tabindex="-1">
            <td class="dijitReset">
                <div class="dijitMenuItemIcon " dojoattachpoint="iconNode"></div>
            </td>
            <td tabindex="-1" class="dijitReset dijitMenuItemLabel" dojoattachpoint="containerNode" wairole="menuitem" role="menuitem" aria-disabled="false">Clone</td>
            <td class="dijitReset" dojoattachpoint="arrowCell">
                <div class="dijitMenuExpand" dojoattachpoint="expand" style="display:none"><span class="dijitInline dijitArrowNode dijitMenuExpandInner">+</span></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is the code:

```
menu = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#dijit_form_DropDownButton_0")
hidden_submenu = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#dijit_MenuItem_31 > td:nth-child(2)")

actions = webdriver.common.action_chains.ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(menu)
actions.click(hidden_submenu)
actions.perform()
```

Comment: Are you able to click on `修改` using selenium.

Comment: @andyw Which element are you unable to click `修改` dropdown or `modify` element? Your code trials please.

Comment: @cruisepandey, yes, I can click {"修改"} dropdown button, but don't know how to find && click the {"modify"} element.

Answer (score 0):

I see your code very similar to the example of [selenium action chains](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.html), why not making it simpler?. You are just moving to the `修改` menu and not performing click on it, so when you try to click on the submenu won't be found

Anyways, if click on `修改` was performed and you still cannot click on submenu, I recomend to add a hardcoded wait time between the clicks like:

```
import time
time.sleep(3)
```

If this works, perform a dynamic wait time and not a hardcoded one